# Excel VlookUp left cell into VBA from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, function, vlookup

*Hi everybody,* my VLookUp function is working so far, now I would like to convert it into a VBA function.

My VLookUp:

```
=VLOOKUP(A6;'[test.xls]Sheet1'!$A:$B;2;0) 'example for Cell A6, which can vary
```

Now I would like to get this into a VBA function which can be called.
So if the function is called "A6" sould be "overwriten" by the left cell of where the function has been called.

I have tried following code:

```
Sub lookup()
        Dim x1 As String
        x1 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).Select
        VLOOKUP(x1,'[test.xls]Sheet1'!$A:$B;2;0)
End Sub
```

What is necessary that it's working as expected?

I'm grateful for any tips.

---

### Update:

Sorry, mabye it wasn't clear. "test.xls" is **another** workbook. The code should  run inside the file called (e.g.) "missing.xls".

Comment: The range you want to do `VLookUp` on, is it in the same workbook or a different workbook? from your example, it looks like your range is in `test.xls` workbook, which may or may not be the same workbook?

Comment: Oh sorry, it's a different workbook with the name "test.xls" and the other workbook is called "missing.xls" in which I would like to run the code.

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods.

## method 1: using `.formula`

```
sub method1()
    dim x1 as range

    set x1 = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1)
    x1.formula = "=VLOOKUP(A6,'[test.xls]Sheet1'!$A:$B,2,0)"
end sub
```

## method 2: using `.value`

```
sub method2()
    dim x1 as range

    set x1 = activecell.offset(0, -1)
    x1.value = application.vlookup(range("A6").value, workbooks("test.xls").worksheets("Sheet1").range("A:B"),2,0)
end sub
```

Comment: Almost as the solution from zipa... But with your examples I got just "syntax error", when I try to call the function. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: @L.Writer which method? I just remove `.select` from my answer.  Please try again.

Comment: I have tried again, but I still receive the syntax error if I try to call the function inside a cell.. :/

Comment: @L.Writer Which method and which line?

Comment: Both methods, by debugging I don't get any error messages. Just if I try to call the function in a cell I'm receiving the syntax error. Trying to call the methods like this: `=method1()`

Comment: Both methods are `Sub`, not `Function`.  You cannot call `Sub` by writing `sub_name` in a cell.

Comment: Oh ok, got it. Then how I'm able to execute / trigger the event? Sorry, don't understand. (btw. just chaning "sub" to "function" is not working, I have tried, because a function which I can call if required would just be the best for me)

Answer (score 1):

This one should do it:

```
Function MyLookup()

    Dim source As Workbook

    Dim current As Range

    Set current = Application.Caller
    Set source = Workbooks("test.xls")

    MyLookup = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(current.Offset(0, -1).Value, source.Sheets(1).Range("A:B"), 2, False)

End Function
```

So `Application.Caller` gets the cell where the function is located and from there you can perform `VLOOKUP()` with `Offset` from that cell.

**EDIT**

For this lookup to work `test.xls` needs to be open.

Comment: Thanks in advance for the code, it seems that I can't figure out how to call the function (MyLookup). I have created a module (seems to be needed) and pasted the code inside this module, but when I enter inside (e.g.) "B7" `=MyLookup()` I got just **"#VALUE!"** - sorry, I'm very newbie with VBA :3

Comment: You are looking in `B7` in which sheet? This performs lookup from `Sheet1!A:B` so your `B7` is within that same range if you are trying in `Sheet1`.

Comment: I would like to call the function in B7 and then the value from A7 should be searched in **another** workbook called "test.xls".

Comment: Thanks for the update, but unfortunately it's still not working for me (same behaviour). By debugging the code I'm receiving following message: **"runtime error "424": Object required"** - do you may have an idea how to solve?